# PHP function returns always 1

Tags: php, function

I have a model function to check if pseudo_exist in my DB :

```
<?php
function pseudo_check($DB, $pseudo) {

    $req = $DB->prepare("SELECT COUNT(pseudo) FROM members where pseudo = ?");

    $req -> execute(array($pseudo));
    $nbre_pseudo = $req->fetch();

    settype($nbre_pseudo, "integer");

    $path = "LOG.txt";
    $ressource = fopen($path, "a");
    fwrite($ressource, "$nbre_pseudo");
    fclose($ressource);

    return ($nbre_pseudo);
    $req->closeCursor();
}
?>
```

Then, I call my function with a controller file :

```
<?php
require_once('models/dbconnect.php');
require_once('models/inscription_functions.php');

pseudo_check($DB, $_POST['pseudo']);

if($nbre_pseudo > 0)
{
    header('location: index.php?page=inscription&error=pseudo_exist');
}
?>
```

- In my function, the '$nbre_pseudo' variable returns '1' each time, I don't understand why..
- I use 'settype' to avoid to return 'Array' , but maybe is there another solution ??

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, use `fetchColumn` method to return a column value (scalar value) instead of a whole row (`fetch`) (I'm assuming you are using PDO). Also, writing any statement after `return` has no sense. Finally, you are calling your function without using the returned value.

Comment: Thank you, so 'fetchColumn' doesn't return an array, right ?   Yes I've forgot               `$var = pseudo_check($DB, $_GET['pseudo']);`   And yes, I wasn't sure, but I put my return after my DB close.  And it works fine, thank you :)

Comment: Yes, it returns a single column value (by default the first column, but it takes an optional argument as column index (0-based). So if you need the 3rd column value, get it with `fetchColumn(2)`

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing settype to prevent an array returning...setting type on an array is not the same as getting the value out of the array.

```
$req = $DB->prepare("SELECT COUNT(pseudo) AS count FROM members where pseudo = ?");

$req -> execute(array($pseudo));
$nbre_pseudo = $req->fetch();

$count = $nbre_pseudo['count']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `settype($nbre_pseudo, "integer")` you are converting an array to an integer. The result is either 0 if the array is empty or 1 if the array is not empty.